Why did Hashem create the Livyasan?
In Parshas Bereishis it says that Hashem created the large fish. Rashi explains that it is referring to the two Livyasans (Leviathans) that Hashem created - a male & a female. He then says that Hashem had to kill the female, because if they would be able to reproduce, there would be no more room in the world for anything else since they are so big.
It is a known thing that Hashem took the Livyasan out of this world and is saving it for a big feast for the Tzadikim in Olam Haba when Moshiach comes - so why did Hashem create the Livyasan if He knew that He wasn't going to need it until Moshiach comes, years later?

And why did He create the female at all?

Correct - it goes under the same question - Hashem obviously knew that it would've been too big to reproduce!

In Sefer Iyov containing Leviathan is brough as an example of Hashem's might for us to marvel as He is able too.  It is also part of a question how the single Leviathan can survive for such a long time, it defies our biological knowledge (unless Hashem somehow make jerkey out of it)?
